# How can I do an opacity mask in Compact Framework?

Tags: compact-framework

I am looking for a way I can do an opacity mask in Compact Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think that the CF version of .Net supports opacity at all. Makes some sense too. Calculating opacity is a very expensive operation, one not well suited to underpowered devices.

That said, here is a [possible workaround.](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2008/01/transparent-controls-in-netcf.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own opacity mask for a Bitmap by simply doing the pixel-by-pixel manipulations yourself.  The super-slow way to do this would be to use the Bitmap's `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods, but a much faster way is to use the LockBits method.  See:

[Bob Powell: Locking Bits](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx)

Depending on what exactly you're doing, Windows Mobile devices have a surprising amount of processing power for this sort of thing.  Iterating through and processing the 76,800 pixels of a 320x240 Bitmap using LockBits takes just a few milliseconds (depending on how complex the "processing" is, of course).  Opacity masking (presumably) involves just comparing two pixel values and possibly calculating a third, so this would be no problem.